# Input not updating value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

As you can see on these photos, I have made an `onclick` event that checks the value of the first input text field . Even if I change it, it will still give the old value.

Here is my function:

```
 $(document).on('click','#editcustomer-btn-save',function(e) {
      var x = $('#id1').val();
      console.log(x);
      e.preventDefault();
    return false;
 });
```

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0):

I note your edit screen appears to be in a modal.

Make sure that in your DOM there aren't two IDs with the same name.  (One in your main page, and one in the modal)

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that it doesn't upgrade ? 
Try with this

```
function displayVals() {
  var x= $( "id1" ).val();
  console.log(x);
}

$( "input" ).change( displayVals );
displayVals();
```